# How to call my authentication microservice in another microservice in spring boot security

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, restful-authentication

I have implemented an authentication service using Spring Security which has access to a database which stores user data. Now I want to implement another service (open a totally new project) where I only specify the url of my authentication service. I used `.loginProcessingUrl()` and changed the login page in the spring security configuration but that does not work. How do I make the new service authenticate using my authentication service?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: yes i do, the problem is on how to call the already implemented authentication service and avoid to use the default one offered by spring security

Comment: Have you tried adding a custom AuthenticationProvider that does just that, to the AuthenticationManager?

Comment: no i did not, i have only changed the url of login page and the loginProcessUrl

Comment: you're using formLogin().loginProcessingUrl() somewhere in your config? I ask because there are many options to accomplish this (like adding filters to the filter chain). It depends on the complexity of what you need. For example, will the new service authenticate itself with the authentication service? How will the authentication service know it's giving info to your service and not someone else's?

Comment: i am not going on such a complex service, i am only looking on how can i perform calling my authentication service to a void implementing it again and also for using only one database of users. And yes i am using formLogin()

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom `AuthenticationProvider` to do the authentication for you.

Here's a barebones example:

1. Create a `CustomRemoteAuthenticationProvider` that calls your authentication service:

```java
public class CustomRemoteAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
               throws AuthenticationException {

        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        // call your authentication service
        // ... and return a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

2. Declare your `CustomRemoteAuthenticationProvider` as a bean (which you could do in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`), which will get picked up and added to the `AuthenticationManager` automatically:

```java
@Bean
public CustomRemoteAuthenticationProvider customRemoteAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new CustomRemoteAuthenticationProvider();
}
```

**Note**: You could do all of this in one step by adding `@Component` directly to `CustomRemoteAuthenticationProvider`. Also, [check out the javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html) for `AuthenticationProvider` for a list of `AuthenticationProvider`s if you want more ideas on how to write one. `DaoAuthenticationProvider` is commonly used with `JdbcDaoImpl` to authenticate against a database.

Comment: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is the filter that'll call your AuthenticationProvider, so you can take a look at it if you want to know exactly what'll be going on

Comment: this sounds verry good but how to call the authentication service

Comment: have i to use restTemplate to pass th url

Comment: Yes you could do that, or HttpClient

Comment: For sure dude i ma trying this i will tell you as soon as possible thank you

Comment: is this valid for API gateway using webflux ?